# Como fazer customização do UIAlertView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Cenário:

Fazer alteração das cores, e botões do `UIAlertView`. Como usar imagens para fazer essa customização. Por exemplo: Adicionar imagem no background, e trocar a cor da tela bloqueada atrás do alerta.

Caso a questão tenha ficado vaga, ou de difícil compreensão, basta fazer um comentário para que eu possa inserir mais informações sobre a dúvida.

Comment: Vale lembrar também que a `UIAlertView` está obsoleta no **iOS 8**, substituída por `UIAlertController`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para customizar um `UIAlertView`, sendo esta uma `UIView` qualquer, você **poderia** simplesmente criar uma subclasse desta e fazer as alterações que deseja, mesmo sobrescrevendo o `layoutSubviews:`, como mostrado **[nesse](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-uialertview-custom-graphics--mobile-8886)** tutorial.

E por que **poderia**? Porque as chances de você conseguir publicar um aplicativo assim é quase **zero**. Veja que na própria **[referência](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html)** desta classe existe uma nota sobre isso, essa classe é privada e não deve ser modificada:

> The `UIAlertView` class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   must not be modified.

Mas como eu disse, `UIViewAlert` é uma `UIView` qualquer, então você pode fazer o seu próprio alerta, isso significa desde o zero, montar sua view com os botões necessários, *background*, *overlay* e *delegates*.

Para isso, a resposta seria bem ampla envolvendo vários detalhes, então recomendo você ao menos iniciar a partir desta ideia e no decorrer do seu desenvolvimento ir tirando as dúvidas.

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado @PauloRodrigues! Vou ver aqui e vou tentar publicar assim mesmo. Obrigado!!

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar o CustomIos7AlertView (http://www.wimagguc.com/2013/10/custom-ios7-uialertview/). Funciona muito bem, mesmo com ios 8.